# access to array into controller codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a problem, this is my model, return many columns, for example (cert_num) :

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('certificado_asegurado');
$this->db->where('certificado_asegurado.cert_id', $search_string);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Now, in my controller i need do other query to other model, but with "cert_num" valor return:

```
$data['certificado'] = $this->certificado_model->get_certificado($search_string);
$cert_num=$data['certificado']['cert_num']->cert_num; //not work
$cert_num= $certificado['cert_num']; //not work
$cert_num=$data['certificado']['cert_num']; //not work
```

I need $cert_num valor for send to model

```
$data['user'] = $this->certificado_model->get_user($cert_num);
```

Any solution please, to retry with foreach but not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

iDont know exactly how your array is being returned but you could try access it from its index just like this

```
$cert_num=$data['certificado'][0]->cert_num;
```

or

```
$cert_num=$data['certificado'][0]['cert_num'];
```